# Can't create foreign key

Tags: java, sql, mysql, hibernate

I'm trying to add a foreign key to an existing table, and was having issues.  I figured that I had an error in my syntax, so I updated my hibernate.cfg.xml file to auto-update.

As it turns out, hibernate had the same error.  Here's my SQL to add the foreign key:

```
alter table pbi add index FKEA3F7BDE9BAB051 (FK_idP), add constraint FKEA3F7BDE9BAB051 foreign key (FK_idP) references p (idP)
```

and the error is:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db`.`#sql-6f8_3`, CONSTRAINT `FKEA3F7BDE9BAB051` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_idP`) REFERENCES `p` (`idP`))
```

Can anyone think of a reason why this would fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error means that constraint can not be applied because there are existing records that would violate it.

In your case, `pbi` table has rows whose `FK_idP` column has a value for which there are no matching records with that value in `idP` column of `p` table.

Comment: Yep, that was it.  I had to remove the NOT NULL clause in the add column query to add the foreign key (or do a migration before adding the key)