# Can't create Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I wrote a [simple SQL](http://freetexthost.com/3tlggyxi0c) statement to create addon for wordpress - just few tables with relations.
 I decided to test it a bit in MySQL workbench and all goes fine, got tables and relations. Then I'm trying to forward engineer it - workbench slightly [changes the text](http://freetexthost.com/btuuhr6gek)... and then reports an error:
[image]

Honestly, I'm quite puzzled here... schema looks very simple, I'm sure I didn't make any type so why the error?

Comment: possible exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400984/cant-create-foreign-key?rq=1

Comment: If `wp_users.ID` is `BIGINT UNSIGNED`, so must the `owner` be.

Comment: yeah, I must be blind... didnt notice the UNSIGNED part

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the columns are the same in both tables including sign for the foreign key and the primary key.

Comment: Yes, now I noticed that ID is BIGINT UNSIGNED

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the engine? InnoDB handles foreign keys, but I think the standard MyISAM doesn't, or at least, didn't always, depending on version.

Comment: This might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371593/mysql-workbench-ignores-foreign-keys?rq=1

Comment: MyISAM does not and never will. The server accepts any FK definition for such an engine but silently ignores it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add the foreign key restriction to an attribute in a table containing data you can have problems if the foreign key restriction is not fulfilled. I mean, if you have a value in the attribute that now is a foreign key, and this value is not contained in the attribute of the table that the foreign key references.